# Enforcing the Use of for Acronyms in LaTeX

Tags: glossaries, overleaf, acronyms, warnings

I am working on a document where I want to enforce the use of acronyms via the `glossaries` package. My intention is to ensure that each acronym is used properly with the `\gls{}` command so that I can keep the spelling consistent throughout the document. I want LaTeX (Overleaf) to throw warnings or errors if an acronym is used without the `\gls` command. Here is a minimal working example (MWE) to illustrate my goal:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  acronym,         % Enable acronym functionality
  nomain,          % No main glossary
]{glossaries}

\newacronym{HTML}{HTML}{Hypertext Markup Language}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{HTML} should be valid whereas the pure usage of ``Hypertext Markup Language'' or ``HTML'' should throw warnings/errors as they are not used with \texttt{\gls\{HTML\}}

\end{document}
```

In this example, the usage of `\gls{HTML}` is correct and should compile without any issues. However, I want LaTeX to flag the instances of `Hypertext Markup Language` and `HTML` (without the `\gls`) as incorrect, and throw either warnings or errors to alert me of the misuse.

Is there a way to enforce this rule, possibly through `glossaries-extra` or a custom command? Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: you can't do this in latex (other than luatex) but you could use an external search tool such as grep or perl (that you could call from overleaf) to search for things. But what do you want to search for, the most likely failure is using a term which is not defined at all,  you could look for all caps eg HTML or XML and say they should be `\gls` but spotting arbitrary phrases that could be made in to acronyms seems hard.

Comment: You could `grep` the definitions of the acronyms you do define and search for instances in the text of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.overleaf.com/read/pdnvqtykcmcs#ede4b2

You can grep (search) for the acronym and its expansion here leaving in `grep.log` which you can see from overleaf's `other logs and files` menu,
It shows the line number and found text.

```
checking HTML
21:`HTML
21:`Hypertext Markup Language
```

from

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  acronym,         % Enable acronym functionality
  nomain,          % No main glossary
]{glossaries}
\NewCommandCopy\xnewaconym\newacronym
\makeatletter
\def\newacronym#1#2#3{%
\xnewaconym{#1}{#2}{#3}%
\immediate\write18{echo checking #1 >>grep.log}%
\immediate\write18{grep -on "[^{}]#2" *.tex >>grep.log}%
\immediate\write18{grep -on "[^{}]#3" *.tex >> grep.log}%
}
\makeatother
\newacronym{HTML}{HTML}{Hypertext Markup Language}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{HTML} should be valid whereas the pure usage of ``Hypertext Markup Language'' or ``HTML'' should throw warnings/errors as they are not used with \texttt{\gls{HTML}}

\end{document}
```

There is currently a live overleaf link to the project above, but I don't guarantee that will stay forever.